# MVC4 Ajax request code 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

Whenever I check the console in the browser, it says it cannot find the URL with a code 404. The URL at which it performs a post is `http://localhost:54473/Date/GetArticleName`.

**The method inside the `DateController.cs`**

```
public JsonResult GetArticleName(long barcode)
{
    ArticleDbContext artdb = new ArticleDbContext();
    Article art = (Article) artdb.Articles.Where(a => a.Barcode == barcode).First();
    return Json(art.Name, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Create.schtml**

```
@model DatoCheckerMvc.Models.Date

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Opret ny";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Opret</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Date", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validationFunction() {
            var isValid = true;
            if (!$("#ArticleBarcode").val() || $("#ArticleBarcode").val() == "" || $("#ArticleBarcode").val().match("^\d+$")) {
                isValid = false;
            }
            if (!$("#RunDate").val() || $("#RunDate").val() == "" || $("#RunDate").val().match("((?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])")) {
                isValid = false;
            }

            if (isValid) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).keydown(function (event) {
                if ((event.keyCode == 13) && (validationFunction() == false)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $("#ArticleBarcode").change(function (event) {
                $.ajax({ //This function is the call to the method.
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetArticleName", "Date")',
                    data: { barcode: $("#ArticleBarcode").val() },
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        var divInsert = document.getElementById("JsonResponse");
                        divInsert.innerHTML = result;
                    },

                    error: function () {

                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dato</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleBarcode)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ArticleBarcode, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleBarcode)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="ArticleName">Varenavn</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <div id="ArticleName">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RunDate)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RunDate, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RunDate)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Opret" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Tilbage", "Index")
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I have:

- Ensured JQuery is loaded at the top
- Tried to use `$.getJson()` instead
- Insert breakpoint in the method to see if it executed (which it did not)

*How can I resolve my issue?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try marking your method with a `HttpPost` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetArticleName(long barcode) {
    ...
}
```

Without the attribute it's assumed to be a `GET` request.

Also, the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` isn't needed if it's going to be a `POST` request.

Comment: This did not resolve the issue but I have found out it is on this line in JQuery it throws the error: `xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );` (jquery-1.9.0.js line 8475)

Comment: This isn't a jQuery error.  You are making a POST request to a resource which doesn't exist.  After adding the attribute did you recompile?

Comment: No I did not but now I recompiled (without editing anything) it just return error code 500 instead.

Comment: I imagine adding the `HttpPost` did the trick and now your 500 error is happening somewhere inside that method.  Check your error logs to see where the exception is being thrown.